# Can we get password keeper data backup if we know the master password?

Tags: blackberry, passwords

The title explains my question. If we get to know the Blackberry's Password keeper's master password, then can we get its data backup. I need this as I'm developing an application which makes a backup of the password keeper database based on the master password the user has set. Thanks a lot in advance.